# How to overlay a small icon over another image on ImageView

Tags: java, android

I have a gridView layout to display images, and i want to place a small icon over the image as marked.

here my code :

```
ImageView i;
    if (convertView == null) {  
        i = new ImageView(mContext);
        i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width, height));
        i.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    } else {
        i = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    if(mImageSet == IMAGE_SET_ONE) { 
            boolean cek = true;
            i.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mContext.getResources(),mThumbIds[position],width,width)); 

    }
```

Please help..

Comment: Try to inflate the convertView from FrameLayout resource instead of creating ImageView in code. Place the ImageView and  view for small icon to this layout. Get acccess to image view and icon view through `findViewById`

Answer (score 4):

The ImageView widget has built in functionality for setting a background and a foreground image. You can check out what it looks like in xml, the src and background fields can be set with the setImageResource and setImageBackground methods on ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/pink"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: First example]

The only problem with this is that the src (overlay) image will match either the height or the width of your image view.

Thus to get around this you are going to have you use multiple image views in a relative and set the background or src on each individually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/pink" />

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Second example]

Comment: @PaulNababan: I think it would be something like i.setBackground(bg_image) and i.setForeground(fg_image)

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:translationZ="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@raw/image" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_photo_camera_24" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Replace your image with srcCompat